# VFP class license error

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

I have the  occasional problem when I try to debug third party plugins sometimes I get OLE error code 0x80040112 class is not licensed for use and sometimes I get you have 14 day left for this demo license what is the cause of this and how can I add break points in these plugins to find the fault.as I am able to rebuild the app and also able to make changes to the main program and build the EXE I am not sure what is causing the problem I have looked on microsoft site but the answers appear to relate to built in VFP classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add class license in the TOOLS>OPTIONS>CONTROLS that will help with the class not licensed error check out this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139154 may have additional help ?

Comment: thank you user2033464 that seems to fix the licensing problem I now need to figure out how to set a break point in the third party plugin

Comment: Hi just been checking out some tools for VFP and found an excellent tool call fish4 it searches your projects for variables and returns every instance of it in a nice GUI and I am currently looking at Thor